# How do I have a Athena query run on a schedule and have the result set sent to an email

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena, aws-glue

I have created a few Athena queries to generate reports.

Business wants these reports run nightly and have the output of the query emailed to them?

My first step is to schedule the execution of the saved/named Athena queries so that I can collect the output of the query execution from the S3 buckets.

Is there a way to automate the execution of the queries on a periodic basis?

Comment: You'll have to build a system that can schedule the triggering of these emails, can retrieve the results, and can send emails. This is too broad for a Stackoverflow question. Which part of that can you begin working on? You might need to do some research.

Comment: Soon using evaluex.io out of the box and fee.

Comment: @KirkBroadhurst thanks for your reply, yes I should narrow down the question  here. I have edited for more clarity. If I have a saved (named) query in Athena, is there a way to run this query on a schedule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can schedule events in AWS using Lambda ([see this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-scheduled-events.html)). From Lambda you can run just about anything, including trigger some Athena query.

Comment: With Lambda I will have to write code to open a JDBC connection, and execute the query, etc, Is there another aws tool where I can simply provide the name of the query and the run schedule?

Comment: No there is not, but you can execute an Athena query in a handful of lines of Python.